# $_GET параметр на русском языке

Tags: url, seo, php, get

Всем привет. Есть ли проблема в том, что $_GET параметр на русском языке в адресной строке?  Например так:

*index.php?r=foods/index&cat=**первое***

Всем спасибо.

Comment: Сформируйте правильно свой вопрос. Ничего не понятно, что вам нужно.

Comment: Вопрос конкретнее не бывет

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, проблема в SEO

Comment: Проблем нет: Кириллица браузерами автоматом преобразуется в юникод.  Скопируйте адрес и вставьте в блокнот - там будет index.php%3Fr%3Dfoods%2Findex%26cat%3D%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5.

Comment: с точки зрения SEO такой адрес нормален? В поисковой выдаче будет отображаться этот хэш ли нет?

Answer (score 2):

Проблемы нету, если его предварительно кодировать функцией наподобии rawurlencode()

Answer (score 0):

Нет проблем, ведь на hashcode тоже есть такие get запросы.
Советую почитать [мануал](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)